# Can I have an incrementing count variable in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linqpad

I want to do something like this:

```
from a in stuff
let counter = 0
select new { count = counter++, a.Name };
```

But I get a error telling me that counter is read only. Is there a way to do something similar to this, without declaring a variable outside of the query?

Basically, I just want to show a count/index column in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (which is awesome, BTW), which means I can't declare counter ahead of time.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Rather than using side-effects, use the overload of `Select` which takes an index:

```
stuff.Select((value, index) => new { index, value.Name });
```

You *could* do it using side-effects, but not in the way you tried:

```
int counter = 0;
var query = from a in stuff
            select new { count = counter++, a.Name };
```

I would strongly advise against this though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not (always) work with entity framework core row sets. A workaround would be to stick these rows in a List first.

Comment: Please explain why you strongly advise against this

Comment: @tjmoore: Because LINQ is designed for pipelines without side-effects. For example, the query I've given at the end will not do anything in itself. That just sets up the pipeline - you have to *use* the query in order for it to count anything... and if will count every time you iterate over `query`. That kind of thing can be really confusing in the real world (as opposed to trivial examples)

Comment: Thanks, works, but remember, it CANNOT BE PERFORMED ON QUERYABLES, only Array, List etc. will work :)

Answer (score 8):

If you truly want it to be a counter, and not just an index, then just move the counter declaration outside the LINQ expression

```
var counter = 0;
from a in stuff
select new { count = counter++; a.Name };
```

Comment: Another answer strongly advises against this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2209014/7724

Answer (score 2):

Just add two variable here `NumberRow` is for that

```
.Select((x,NumberRow) => new ViewModelArchiveOrder
                    {
                        NumberRow= NumberRow + 1,
                    })
```